# how to "Migrate the plugin to the pubspec platforms manifest"

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, package

I have created a new flutter app and after adding cloud_firestore 0.13.0+1 it will not compile. No errors it just stops and removes the row of compile icons. An Analysing spinner revolves forever.

In pub.dev it says to "Migrate the plugin to the pubspec platforms manifest." unfortunately I have been unable to find out where that is or how to do it in the documents or StackOverflow. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup#add-flutterfire-plugins), the plugins you required need to be added under dependencies in to a  pubsec.yaml file located in the root of your project.

```
dependencies:
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0+1
```

After your plugins are added to pubsec.yaml, you can make use of those dependencies in your code by using [imports](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore).

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
```

Comment: Of course, that had been done, but even if it had not the compile just stopped with no error message. I gather what you are saying is the "pubspec platforms manifest" is the pubspec file.

Comment: Yes, i meant the pubsec file as the pubsec platforms manifest, and according to [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup#add-flutterfire-plugins), that file is located at the root of a project.